# Jquery special character handling for IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

This is a bit embarrassing scenario but I need solution.

I am using some names as an ID for li HTML element. These names are having special characters in it. using JQuery to grab an Id.

lets say my id usage is

```
var abc = li[id="someCompany=\"Some Term\""]
```

if I am calling this as

```
alert($(abc).parent()[0]); or 
alert($(abc).html());
```

I am getting data and everything is working fine in **firefox** but not in **IE**.

My actual id display in application is

```
<li id="someCompany=&#034;Some Term&#034;"> xyz </li>
```

I am replacing it with .replace(/"/gi, "\"")

Please let me know, How to get it work in IE, Thanks in advance

**Sorry guys, I need to give more information in my question...**

Firstly, I get ID as

```
var aaa = "someCompany=&#034;some Data&#034;";
```

I am replacing it as

```
aaa = aaa.replace(/&#034;/gi, "\"").replace(/&#039;/gi, "\'").replace(/&amp;/gi, "\&");
```

Then,

```
var abc = aaa.replace(/"/gi, "\\\"").replace(/\:/gi, "\:").replace(/'/gi,"\\\'");
```

and then my question follows....
When I tried changing the above line to

```
var abc = aaa.replace(/"/gi, "\"").replace(/\:/gi, "\:").replace(/'/gi,"\'");
```

everything is fine but I have some names like

```
var aaa = "someCompany=&#034;some's Data&#034;"; //In this case I need to handle more special chanracters
```

Here, `.replace(/"/gi, "\\\"")` is working fine in Firefox but not in IE. How can I make it work in IE as well, please suggest

Comment: Just a suggestion, consider using data-* instead of cramming all of that into the id and then having to finagle it.

Comment: In my above example I just gave it as xyz but there is lot more in it actually

Comment: Then these are the rules for an id attribute in an html 4 site:
"ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")."

Comment: I agree but this is a really weird scenario that I don't have any id. I need to depend on this only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using browser validation, like single quotes and slash in IE and double in FF.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE are you using? I'm on IE9, and on jsFiddle, that works in IE for me (in IE7/8/9 standards mode as well). The only difference I have between your code and mine is that I put quotes around abc, i.e. var abc = 'li[id="someCompany=\"Some Term\""]' ... I'd assume you already had that there though?

http://jsfiddle.net/benno_007/mhHJh/2/

Although .parent()[0] returns an object, not xyz. If you're just needing to access xyz, just use $(abc).html()

Edit:

An alternative to using those awkward IDs could be:

```
<li id="someCompany" term="Some Term">test</li>

$('#someCompany[term="Some Term"]').html();
```

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/benno_007/mhHJh/3/

Comment: I already mentioned I tried $(abc).html(). Still not able to get it. Tried in IE6, IE7, IE8

Comment: Hmm, I guess IE9s standards mode must be completely different to the actual browser. Are you able to try my other suggestion I just appended to my answer? You'd have to test that jsFiddle link on your IE versions, because they all work from my IE9, but thats meaningless if they render completely differently lol.

Comment: Sorry, thats really weird... is anything at all being alerted in IE? null? undefined? an empty string? If its null, it should mean that the selector isnt being identified properly by IE (maybe IE tries to convert the htmlentities to something else). I read a few things saying to try double/triple escaping the quotes in the selector, but I dunno if that'll help in this case... im downloading IE tester to see if I can find anything else... On another note, I'm unsure if using alert($('li').filter('li[id=someCompany][terms="Some Terms"]').html()); will work, but its worth a try?

Comment: Hey, sorry I need to give more details for my question. I just edited my question, please check once

Comment: Is it not possible to output the ' in some's data as a &#039;?

Answer (score 0):

```
var abc = $("[id='someCompany=\"Some Term\"']");
alert($(abc).html()); //returns xyz
```

works for me in IE7 and 8, only difference is the single quotes around the whole attribute value instead of the doubles you have

Comment: sorry, this works.. please check my updated question for my requirement.